# JAVA : Check if Collection of object with start and end dates are overlapping - best way

Tags: java

I've multiple  List of Java-Datetimes with MyCustomDate  object contains  ( start DateTime and end DateTime )  **LocalDateTime with hours and seconds.**

I need to write function to check if There is Overlapping dates in my list return true \ false  - **with the best performance**

can use java8 (stream functions)

Comment: What is your current solution and why is it too slow? What constitutes "too slow" or "fastest" for you? How many elements will be in the lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to test all ranges aginst each other. There is no other way. Try this way, although is just one implementation, there are plenty of correct ways to implement it:

```java
public boolean isThereOverlapingRanges(List<CustomDateRange> ranges) {
    if (ranges.size() <= 1) {
        return false;
    }
    boolean overlaping = false;
    for(int i = 1; i < ranges.size(); i++) {
        if (isDateInRange(ranges.get(0).start(), ranges.get(i)) ||
            isDateInRange(ranges.get(0).end(), ranges.get(i))) {
                overlaping = true;
                break;
        }
    }
   return overlaping || isThereOverlapingRanges(ranges.subList(1, ranges.size());
}

private boolean isDateInRange(DateTime date, CustomDateRange range) {
    return date.after(range.start()) && date.before(range.end());
}
```

Comment: nice idea but what about to sort the list before and then check just two places

Comment: Because you can have sorted dates all or non overlaped. By which date would you sort? Start of range or end?. "Sort it first" sounds appealing, but the sorting itself is just a bulk of comparissons exaclty the same as the ones that you pretend to avoid... by sorting.

Comment: it was questions for senior java developer and i think your way is good preformence but the intervier give idea to order start date first